# Keyboard shortcut

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I love keyboard shortcuts on Android Studio. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> navigates between methods inside java class file. Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate up and down the warnings and errors in this fashion?

Comment: F2 and Shift + F2 will navigate between errors. Is there a way to navigate between Warnings

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will navigate between errors and warnings.

**Credits:**

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904222/keyboard-shortcut#comment47931151_29904222) by [Guillermo Alvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4731474/guillermo-alvarez)

And https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html

**Additional References**

PDF of Keymap Reference for IntelliJIDEA (Windows/Linux)
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

PDF of Keymap Reference for IntelliJIDEA (MAC)
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf